# remove element from ngrepeat using filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I mark an element in an array as deleted and hide it by using a filter? I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
<li ng-repeat="user in preferences.users | filter:user.removed">
  <button ng-click="user.removed=1">delete</button>
  {{user.id}}
</li>
```

Comment: I set up a fiddle to show the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/2459/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `user` in your filter, and change to bools:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{removed:false}">
   <button ng-click="user.removed=true">remove</button>
</div>
```

edit: here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y2e3F/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting user.removed to true instead of 1.